# How to shift 4 decimal places in a number using DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to convert $11,120.6 million to 1.12 billion. My question is how to shift by 4 decimal places every time after the decimal point since I will be inserting values dynamically in excel.

Comment: How shifting 11,120.6 by 4 will create 11.2?

Comment: How is the value stored?  How is it represented to begin with?

Comment: Shifting by 4 decimals must give 111.2

Comment: Sorry really sorry i misunderstood what i had to do  i meant shifting it 4 decimals ahead from the decimal point.I want to make $11,120.6 million to 1.12 billion.Can one one guide me for this.

Answer (score 2):

**Original title was a bit misleading, so my answer provides more than one way of accomplishing this task.  First part reflects the answer to the new title.**

11,120.6 shifted by four decimal places to the left will not create 1.12; more like 1.112 or 1.11 (depending on the number of decimal places).  But anyways, here are some thoughts:

DecimalFormat way:

```
float num = 11120.6;
DecimalFormat numFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println(numFormat.format(num));
```

If it's purely visual, you can just do something like this:

```
float num = 11120.6;
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", num));
```

That one will give you two decimal places to the right of the decimal point, producing 1.11.

Or how about something like this?

```
float num = 11120.6;
num /= 10000.0;
```

This will give you 1.11206.

You can create *if else* logic or something similar to divide/multiple by an appropriate amount, based on the number, i.e.:

```
if (num >= 10)
{
    num /= 10.0;
}
else if (num >= 100)
{
    num /= 100.0;
}
...etc...
```

You can also do something like this along with the similar logic to above:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("11120.6");
num = num.movePointRight(-4);
```

Unless someone can think of a better way you'll also need to know that the number before was in millions representation and the new number is in billions.  Store it in a separate variable as an enumeration, perhaps.

Something else you can do, but it's **not very efficient**, is what we did in my C++ class in college when we were messing around.  You can create several arrays or lists (depending on what it is that you do) for certain number sizes.  When you want to display a number of say... listBillions, you'd divide any number from that list by 1000000000.0, or format it as a string. So, in the the end you have your lists of dozens, hundreds, thousands, etc., and you'll always know that listBillions[i] can be nothing but a billion in whatever form it is being displayed.

Comment: By using decimal format i am able to do it now.thank you all for your help.

Comment: @user3209213 No problem.  I think I misread your title. You meant 'number' by 'no' and I thought you can't use it.  Updated my answer for others to reflect that.  Kept the rest of the information as other options.